# Python/Xpath - how to scrape an href field

Tags: python, lxml, scrape, scraper

As an example, from the following page I would like to extract the team name

http://www.scoresandodds.com/grid_20150409.html

I tried:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

pageNBA = requests.get('http://www.scoresandodds.com/grid_20150409.html')
treeNBA = html.fromstring(pageNBA.text)
team = treeNBA.xpath('//a[@href="/statfeed/statfeed.php?page=nba/nbateam&amp;teamid=CHICAGO&amp;season="]/text()')
```

I think my problem is in the team line where I'm defining the location, how should I locate an href.

Answer (score 0):

you can use xpath as follow:

#### XPath selector expression

```
//td[@class='name']/a
```